# Программа не может найти метод toUpperCase()

Tags: java, lambda

В коде ниже компилятор говорит что не может найти метод toUpperCase(),почему?

```
interface FunInterface {
    String func(String parametr);
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "okfr";
        a = bigSimbols(a::toUpperCase, a);
    }

    static String bigSimbols(FunInterface fun, String s) {
        return fun.func(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = bigSimbols(String::toUpperCase, a);
```

Comment: А так же надо делать со статическими методами а типо toUpperCase не статический